# How to fix code generation error when trying to add a Razor View using VS2019

Tags: asp.net-core, code-generation, razor-pages

I am using VS2019 and trying to add a RazorPage view. When trying to attempt that, i am given a code generation error and not sure how to fix that. im using asp.net core version 2.2.0

Ive tried to "build solution" and "restore NuGet Packages" thinking it would help.Error still exist.

pic of error:

[image]

UPDATE: ERROR I GET WHEN TRYING TO INSTALL THE CODEGENERATOR

[image]

Comment: Have you installed the package(check in dependencies->NuGet)?Have you try to reopen the vs 2019?

Comment: @XingZou I’ve tried to reopen. I uninstalled and reinstalled vs2019. I checked the dependencies and tried to install via package manager console and it won’t install. You think it’s because i am trying to use vs2019?

Comment: @XingZou the code generation is in the “NuGetFallback” folder but, it’s not listed when in VS2019 when i click on NuGet and want to view the packages